# Visual Studio Git-commit shows too many changes

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, commit

Every time I open new visual studio project that is linked to Github I have more than 80000 changes in my project already. Has anybody encountered with such problem?
Here is what I mean:
[image]

[image]

How is it possible and why does it happen? And more importantly, how can I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: proposed questions do not solve my problem. I suppose the problem is that git files (.gitignore, .gitconfig..) are placed in wrong directory (Korisnik which means User in english) so it catches so many changes. Where should I put these files?

Comment: As a wild guess, I'd say `.dotnet` should be added to `.gitignore`. And probably `.config` too.

Comment: I'm not sure how do I do that. I googled it and opened Git repository settings-->git files->.gitignore `edit`.When I click on `edit` it just opens a bunch of code in my solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init+home

Comment: It looks like you made your home directory a Git repo by accident. Follow the link posted by phd yesterday for several questions related to your problem.